# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value

Tags: java, hibernate

Am using Hibernate 3.6

Below is `Employee` class code.

```
public class Employee {

private int id;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Below is `Employee.hbm.xml` file,

```
<class name="com.testing.hibernate.Employee" table="HIB_EMPLOYEE">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
            This class contains the Employee details.
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="sequence"></generator>
      </id>
      <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"></property>
      <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string"></property>
      <property name="salary" column="salary" type="int"></property>            
  </class>
```

I have created sequence in Database. Below SS for reference. How can I overcome the exception that am getting?
[image]

Comment: Post your code for Query!

Comment: what is the database you are using

Comment: @samba Its Oracle 10g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to give the reference of the sequence to hibernate.

```
<generator class="sequence">
     <param name="sequence">SEQUENCE_NAME</param>
</generator>
```

Answer (score 1):

What annotation can i use to do this?

i've tried

`@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE , generator = <SEQUENCE_NAME>")`
without any success

edit:

it seams that the generator have to also be created

`@SequenceGenerator(name="<GEN_NAME>", sequenceName="<SEQUENCE_NAME>")`

Comment: I think that first annotation must be with `generator = "<GEN_NAME>"` (NOT with sequence_name)